# Which GPU would you recommend for this particular workload?

Tags: graphics-cards

I have a very particular workload that requires GPU (OpenCL mandatory) acceleration.
However, from what I hear, GPU are optimized for **floating points** computing, where the task I need acceleration for requires a lot of **Integer** computing, and those Integer computing scores are kinda hard to find.

More specifically (out of the whole data sent to the GPU), the workload consist of:

**- 60% of 8 bits unsigned integer, mostly used for performing ADDITIONS (adding random bytes together)


- 20% of 64 bits unsigned integer, again, mostly used for performing ADDITIONS (adding random bytes together)


- 20% of 32 bits floats, used for performing trigonometry on results from previous Integers sums**

Unrelated points that may affect the choice :
A lot of memory chunk transfer ([1 MB to 30MB]) from the CPU -> GPU, and vice versa, by multiple threads at the same time.
The more memory, the better.
Speed is important, but multiple GPU is an option if necessary.

All OpenCL benchmark I can see do not have these specific informations (mostly, **Integer** related information) in their score.

Do you have a GPU in mind that would be convenient for such task ?
Thanks a lot guys !

Comment: V100 - P100 - K80

Comment: Perfect , thank you so much ! Any reason why those GPU in particular would be best suited for the task ?

Comment: Do you mean **bits** or **bytes**? That's a huge difference for determining which hardware to recommend... Also, what do those percentages represent? What kind of operations are being done on those variables?

Comment: ...dumb mistake, sorry about that. I mean bit. I modified the original question to give more info about the kind of work begin done. Thank you for your input !

Comment: I still have to track down some benchmarks to come up with a recommendation, but the [AIDA64](https://www.aida64.co.uk/user-manual/gpgpu-benchmark) software will benchmark similar operations and at least tell us where GPUs stand relative to each other for FP32 and int64 performance. I can tentatively say now that NVIDIA GPUs are faster than AMD for 64-bit integer ops. Most GPUs do not have a 64-bit ALU at all, so they emulate 64-bit operations in 32-bit.

Comment: Do you have any more details about your workload you can provide? It might help us get some reference numbers, even if it's not exactly the same. Also, you specify a lot of CPU -> GPU memory transfers; is this because they're tightly coupled, or just because there's a lot of data that needs to be loaded onto the GPU? This last point is particularly important, as this can be a huge bottleneck (at least in my experience with NN training), but cards with large amounts of VRAM also cost significantly more than their consumer-grade coutnerparts. Finally, along these lines, **what's your budget**?

Comment: Depending, it might also be worth investing in a platform that can better support your workload. Do you already a machine you're planning on installing these GPUs into? If so, what is it? If not, what would be your budget for such a machine, and would you be willing to build it yourself/buy used?

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your answers ! It helped me quite a bit. I'm gonna check out the AIDA64 scores of various GPUs, but from what I can see, the best [Memory IO + RAM + Computing Power + Price] ratio for this workload would be 2x (two) RTX 2080Ti GPUs. (Perhaps thinking of throwing a Threadripper 3970X in there).  Let me know if you see anything that's wrong with this setup. Thanks again guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the benchmarks found [here](https://www.servethehome.com/xfx-amd-radeon-rx-5700-xt-update-and-review/3/)
, the GIOPS (Integer Operation Per Second) for the Nvidia 2080Ti is second only to the RTX Titan, but for 1/3 the price. 
Since this specific workload contains a lot of small chunck of memory transfer, It seems like two 2080Ti(s) are the logical choice all domain (budget, memory IO, ram, computing power) considered.

Answer (score 0):

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/inside-volta/

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/mixed-precision-programming-cuda-8/

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1038492/cuda-programming-and-performance/question-about-64-bit-integer-performance/

> With the exception of converting between 64-bit integer types and floating-point types, the double-precision units in the GPU have no bearing on 64-bit integer performance.... 64 bit integer is done by emulation.

I know taking advantage of fp16 versus the typical fp32 results in significant gain.

Otherwise **i think** integer performance on a gpgpu follows the benchmarking or reporting you always see for floating point... which is to say you don't gain anything by having integer math over floating point on a gpgpu and since the majority of interest is in floating point calculations that's why you see them.  In any case if you can code your problem in OpenCL (or CUDA) to take advantage of gpu then it will be faster than running the executable on cpu.

I don't think your stated workload would have any bearing on gpgpu choice of architecture.  There is no specific gpu that favors your specific workload.  OpenCL/Cuda basically runs on any gpu so you would want to buy the latest/fastest gpgpu that your budget allows, which is currently an Nvidia V100.  After that it's a debate which card is faster and has a better price/performance ratio.

you also don't have to buy a "gpgpu" such as a V100 or P100 or K80, you can also get a < $300 *graphics card* that will **allow** you to run your OpenCL code but whether the performance is up to par for your needs I don't know you didn't mention that.  A *GPGPU* is the hardware that is favored to run OpenCL or Cuda.  Also know OpenCL is opensource supported by both AMD gpu's and Nvidia gpu's, whereas CUDA is Nvidia proprietary and only supported on Nvidia gpu's.  And CUDA is generally favored over OpenCL for best possible performance.